# Contact with no signal?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

*I know this problem might be too silly/easy, but I'll ask it anyway and see what happens...*

> One day Alice woke up a beach. She got up to look around but there was
>   no one else there! She started to panic a little and then grabbed her
>   phone. She had no bars on her phone (so no reception with her
>   provider)! Settling down, she started tapping her screen and pressing some
>   buttons and was able to call home (but still having no bars)!

**How was Alice able to call home?**

Note:

- She has a normal smartphone (will proper software/apps etc.) but it has no satellite capabilities or other methods to strengthen cellphone signal.
- She has no other technological devices or tools on her except for her phone. (And there aren't any hidden in or on the sand etc.)
- Her 'home' isn't on the island. None of her family is on the island etc.
- She isn't crazy and imagining the call, or sleeping and dreaming etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a public beach with facilities, one method that may have worked for Alice is:

> She may have enabled a WiFi connection and placed a call using a phone app. Free WiFi is offered for many establishments so as long as one is nearby, the problem is solved.

Possible alternative:

> She could also have used Bluetooth or similar technology to connect to a source connected to the internet/cell tower (which would require special software on the receiving end).

Comment: This was my intended answer..Told you it was easy :p

Comment: @MarkN As someone who's stingy with my minutes, I do this on a daily basis =)

Comment: Perhaps you would be willing to expand on your answer a little more to explain the situation?

Comment: why would this exist on an island with "no one else there"?

Comment: Not necessarily an island, just a beach. Perhaps it was too windy, or just late at night.

Comment: @thronofthree no one else was on the beach or in sight when she woke up.